# Regex issue when trying to extract "When Not x Is Nothing"

Tags: c#, regex

I am having an issue with matching a statement using Regex in C#

```
Statement:  "When Not x Is Nothing" 

Pattern: "When Not [\.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing"
```

This pattern also matches the statement `"When x Is Nothing"` which I don't want to happen. 
Any suggestions on how to improve the matching with the statement intended are highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't replicate your problem.  Please show us the code you use to make the match.  Also, your brackets and period need to be escaped: `[\.0-9a-zA-Z_\(\)]`

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, those don't need any escapes in a character class. Sid, it should not match that, you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: The regex works fine for me, I have tested it in Kodos, a graphical regex evaluator. The only thing I can imagine is that you should place `^` before and `$` after the regex. That means the string starts with When... and ends with ...thing. So that would give us `"^When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing$"` forthermore I would advice to use an `@` before the string if you work with a regex, this exculdes escape characters. (I think the comment of @Hand-E-Food otherwise would fail)

Comment: @CommuSoft, I've learned from past experience to always test before I post.  :-)  My suggestion, while unnecessary, works.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: My Regex Had  aspacing issue before "Not" in the pattern other than that it worked in Visual Studio 2010. Thank you

Comment: @Qtax: Thanks, yes I had something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

in LINQPad, that regex appears to work fine (as others have said)

source:

```
var testStrings = new[]
{
    "When Not x Is Nothing",
    "When x Is Nothing",
};

var regex = new Regex("When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing");

foreach (var test in testStrings)
{
    var match = regex.IsMatch(test);
    String.Format("regex {0} matches string {1} ? {2}", regex, test, match).Dump();
}
```

result:

> regex When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing matches string When Not x
>   Is Nothing ? True
>
> regex When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing matches
>   string When x Is Nothing ? False

Comment: James: Thank for the solution, I has pattern "When  Not x Is Nothing" with two spaces before "Not". Your code helped.

Answer (score 2):

On the risk of downvoting. This returns `False` to the console:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing");
Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("When x Is Nothing"));
```

So I think

- The regex you wrote is wrong, or at least inconsistent with the regex here
- You did something wrong in your C# code (for instance have a pointer to the wrong regex)
- You are working with a broken API

Personally I would write:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^When Not [.0-9a-zA-Z_()]* Is Nothing$");
```

to make it more safe, but I don't know if you are matching a string or are searching for a substring.

Comment: CommuSoft: I was matching a string, The Regex I wrote was wrong in the spaces before "Not" other than that the Regex was working.Your Regex also worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Hint: Kodos is a useful tool to test Regular Expressions, and as far as I know it's freeware.